# Does DA deletes SPAM POSTS permanently?

Tags: discussion

Under my flag summary when I mouse over on SPAM POSTS I see the 'POST content' as tooltip.

[image]

My question is Does DA permanently deletes the SPAM? or it keeps only trimmed data of the SPAM for tooltip?

If so Why? Why do they keep that data?

Answer (score 2):

Content is not hard deleted. Since you are not a 10K user, and the post is not yours, you cannot see it after it is deleted; otherwise, the flag would link you to the deleted post.

Comment: Thanks kiamlaluno, yes I understand that. but  they can't be reopened any way. So why don't they delete SPAM permanently.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan There are many reasons. First, sometimes really bad, but non-spam, question about OPs own site may be flagged as SPAM. By mistake. In that case, it can potentially get undeleted. And keeping SPAM samples helps to teach anti-SPAM learning algorithms. Or to manually tune anti-SPAM tools, as you can see [here](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3058/lots-of-question-related-to-weight-lose-fatty-tissue-etc-in-daily-is-it-added#comment4226_3059).

Comment: @Mołot Interesting points!!. Thanks :)